SSL purportedly working but site still coming up as unsecure
I have two websites running on the same server, set up in the exact same way and who's domains are both hosted with cloudflare, again set up identically. One of them works completely fine and the other will periodically be seen by browsers as unsecure for seemingly no reason. Every SSL testing app says it's completely fine, there's no mixed content, I even currently have its public html folder completely empty right now but for an index file with one line of text. Still unsecure. This domain used to have this problem as well when I had it under a different registrar and hosting service, and it was the same situation then, everything was set up exactly how it should be, everything was saying it was fine, but it was unsecure. Please help me, give me some clues as to what the problem could possibly be, I'm really losing my mind over this, it's so frustrating
I've tried getting new SSL certificates, changing cloudflare settings to try and refresh something, deleting the entire website's contents to see if something was wrong and then clearing all the cache, checked every SSL test I could find repeatedly, used multiple devices, different networks...

It can happen that somehow the browser cache has it in unsecure state. Try clearing your browser cache. Alternatively, you can consider forcing a secure connection or fail using htaccess or other methods.

i've cleared the cache, forced and not forced secure connection in every way that i can find, used browsers and devices that have never seen the site before. i dont know. sometimes it works fine and then out of nowhere it wont without me having done a single thing to change it

Does this error pop up for everyone, or just you ?

Have you inspected the connection that you get, secure or not? What certificate do browsers show – does it match the one you've configured on the server? Does it differ between "secure" and "unsecure" occasions? What does Qualys' SSL Labs analyzer say about it?

im not sure if everyone would have the same error all the time, but others have when this has happened in the past, and dont think they wouldnt currently

when its working it has the certificate it should have, same one as the other website. when its not working it shows that theres no certificate to look at. ssl labs gives it all As when TLS 1.0,1.1 arent enabled and doesnt show anything wrong that i can see, both when the site is working and when its not. its functionally identical to the other site, which always works

"Every SSL testing app says it's completely fine," - can you be more specific what you've tried? Have you've checked https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html ?

yes ive checked that

what ciphersuite are up-to-date browsers negotiating with your server? you can see that in Chrome opening the dev tools and going to the security tab. it will look somthing like "TLS_DHE_DSS_AES_256_CBC_SHA256" (note that's an outdated one, just an example). then compare it to a browser that displays the warning. in all likelihood you have old insecure ciphers allowed by your server. it may be negotiating an insecure key exchange or hashing algorithm or mode setting. you can look up TLS ciphersuite info here: https://ciphersuite.info/search/?page=1&q=tls

Thank you, I will look into that

also, are these sites on the same IP address? if so you must have SNI enabled. have you configured a default SNI site for the server on that IP? default SNI only manifests if the client doesn;t send legible hostname information for one reason or another, and if you haven't told the server which site to use as the default when no SNI host information is presented, the server doesn't know what to do. that might explain your experience where it doesn't seem like a certificiate is available for the connection at all. just a thought.

ive been looking into this. the websites are hosted on the same server, theyre ran through a control panel called hestiacp which seems to me like it handles that automatically and i cant find a way to interact with it, but its meant to be used for hosting multiple domains with one ip address and i cant find anyone else having an issue with sni. of course, something could have gone wrong somewhere. thanks a lot for pointing out potential issues

well its not secure again. this time it's only not secure on firefox, but its not secure on multiple different devices with firefox. this has happened before. SSL_ERROR_RX_RECORD_TOO_LONG is the error. it was working on firefox yesterday. this is so miserable

Is your client running some form of security software that intercepts HTTPS?

Not on purpose... I wouldn't think so, but I'm not totally sure. This is such a troublesome error for just a hobbyist to encounter. It's crazy that I literally can't find a single other person having this issue with the same circumstances. The depreciation of search engines probably isn't helping but it seems really rare
